# In Python, what is the easiest way to find the smallest value in a list which contains both strings and floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code asks for a list of products or loads them from a file. Then, I need to find which of the values is the smallest, and if there are equally small elements, choose a random one. However, I still need to link the value to its relevant string. So far I have:

```
def checkPrices(products):

    for x in range(len(products)):
        if (x)%3 == 0:
            name = str(products[x])
            print(name)
        elif (x+1)%3 == 0:
            quantity = int(products[x])
            print(quantity)
            pricePerUnit = str(format(price/quantity, '.2f'))
            print(name + " is $" + pricePerUnit + " per unit")

        elif (x)%1 == 0:
                price = float(products[x])
                print(price)
```

How can I extend this so that I can find the smallest price per unit and then print something like:

```
I would recommend product1
```

Comment: What exactly does this list look like?

Comment: ['product1', '18.5', '72', 'product2', '33', '84', 'product3', '18.50', '72', 'product4', '22', '96']

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that instead of storing all 3 values for everything in a flat list, like you seem to be...

```
["product1", "3", "0.15", "product2", "4", "0.40"]
```

...that you instead store them as a list of tuples:

```
[("product1", 3, 0.15), ("product2", 4, 0.40)]
```

This keeps the logical grouping per-item, and lets you do things like...

```
product_info = [("product1", 3, 0.15), ("product2", 4, 0.40)]
cheapest_product = min(product_info, key=lambda product: product[2] / product[1])

product_name, quantity, total_price = cheapest_product
print "I would recommend %s" % product_name
```

---

**Note**: If all you have is that flat list and you want to convert it to a tuple list...

```
products = ["product1", "3", "0.15", "product2", "4", "0.40"]
products_iter = iter(products)
product_tuples = zip(products_iter, products_iter, products_iter)
product_info = [(i[0], int(i[1]), float(i[2]) for i in product_tuples]
```

and `product_info` will now be the list of tuples I described above.

Comment: that would involve rewriting a large portion of my code so is there a way to do it in this format?

Comment: @user2368334 - yes, go through the list with an index i, and if i%3 == 0, then product name is at x+0, quantity at x+1 and price at x+2.

Comment: @user2368334 see the note I added.

Answer (score 1):

Group your `products` into three  to unflatten it:

```
grouped = zip (*[iter(products)] * 3)
```

Then take the min...

```
recommended = min(grouped, key=lambda (name, qty, price): float(price) / int (qty))[0]
```